# Problem with React Google Maps API - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCenter' of null

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, typeerror

I found this example on Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ir5ks

It is very similar to what I need for my project but I am getting an error that I can't seem to fix. I've copied his exact code except the last two lines which I changed to export default so that I can import it where needed.

When I run my React App it's just returning a blank screen and in the console it says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCenter' of null
at $i.onCenterChanged (App.js:87)

which is this line of code here:   onCenterChanged={() => setCenter(mapRef.getCenter().toJSON())}

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. And do you mean with "last two lines" that you removed `rootElement` and `ReactDOM` from `index.js`, because you shouldn't remove that.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that `mapRef` has not been assigned yet. It is surprising, because it should have been taken care of by `loadHandler`. You should look into it, otherwise you will run into issues when trying to do anything with the map component.
Anyway, you can prevent the error by checking before accessing:

```
onCenterChanged={() => mapRef && setCenter(mapRef.getCenter().toJSON())}
```

Comment: After making your change I get a new error:
Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

All I've done is npx-create-react-app and changed nothing except added a line with:
export default App. Otherwise my code is exactly as the example from codesandbox (with the change from your answer)

Comment: As said, your code sounds like it has multiple issues. Please share a sandbox with a minimal reproducoble example, otherwise it is impossible to help.

Comment: Ive made rar archive and uploaded it to my google drive:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LSyUyJuZSYeGV_Xbfr0-NwyaEsNwETe4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I do not have access. I suggest you to write an example from scratch on an online IDE such as https://codesandbox.io

Comment: Sorry - you should have access now

Comment: I am not willing to download and extract an archive from a stranger on the internet. I am sure you will find your bug. Happy coding!

Comment: That is understandable but it sounded like you didn't mind in your previous reply - and thank you for trying to help. I didn't know any other way of showing you all the files of my react app though and I already provided a link to codesandbox.io in my original post. Mine is literally a copy/paste of that with 1 extra line of code at the end: "export default App"

Comment: If the code is the same, then I suggest to investigate the dependencies and the build process. For example: Have you made sure to import @react-google-maps/api? Are you using the same packae versions? Can you inspect and verify your output bundle?

Comment: Yes I had already installed @react-google-maps/api as per the instructions on https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/ but it looks like he might be using a more recent version? Ive taken a screenshot that compares the two package.json files - https://i.imgur.com/jfO5z92.jpg
I installed mine using npm install --save @react-google-maps/api so I would assume it always uses the most recent one?

Answer (score 0):

The example I found on sandcodebox.io was using a much older package version (even though the version number looks to be higher) and his example does not work with the most recent @react-google-maps/api.

When I reverted back to version 1.3.0 (the same he used) then it all worked as it should.

Thanks to Louis Coulet for the help.

Comment: Glad to have helped!